# Cannot update an datetime object mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I find it very hard and i cannot explain why i cannot update a datetime object but when i am inserting a row into the table with the exact same way, it works.

```
$now= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "UPDATE students SET lastvisit=". $now. " WHERE id=4";
```

I used the exact same way(with $now variable and then pass it into VALUES() ) and the insert statement was successful. Do i have to do it with another way?

Comment: `$now` is a string, not an integer it needs to be quoted. You should use parameterized queries... or you could use `now()` in the query if the database server and PHP are set for the same timezone.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php